# View a picture as IU in the viewport

Tags: 3d-view

I want to display an image in the viewport. the image must always remain facing the In User (as a UI).
I thought to paste the image on a plane, but I know how to keep the plane facing the screen (the track "camera viewport" is possible?)
[image]

Comment: You can draw a 2D texture into all viewport windows with open-gl using python and the bgl module: https://www.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_2_77_0/bgl.html.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you want to see this image purely as reference when working on your scene. For that purpose, it would be enough to use a small area of your blender screen layout as UV/Image Editor. You can force the UV/Image Editor to always display your image by using the pin icon in the UV/Image editor.
[image]

Comment: This is for an addon, I need to display the image in the viewport

Answer (score 1):

Under the properties panel, enable background images, then click the arrow to open its tap.  Click the open button and select the background image and mess with its settings to fit your needs.

Comment: To my knowledge the background images are visible only in predefined ortho views (Top ortho, Left ortho ...)

Answer (score 0):

You could try and parent it to a Camera object, adjust it's positioning and then use the option *Lock Camera to View* under the 3D view <kbd>N</kbd> Properties Panel > View > Lock Camera to View.

You'll have to always use the camera view though, if you exit to any other view the image won't be visible, but with the above option it will behave very similarly.

Comment: I need other views. I can not stay in that camera view

Comment: With that option "Lock Camera to View" active you can get all other views (Top, Bottom, Left Right, Ortho etc) while in camera view as if it was a regular viewport view.

Comment: When I'm camera view I can not have all the usual functionality eg "View All"...